# packaging selenium code as jar

Tags: java, selenium

I need to package my selenium script (exported as JUnit4 test) as jar file to be used by some third part application.
Is such a thing supported? If yes, how can this be done and how would the manifest file look like?

Comment: I guess I am a bit late, but yes, that of course works. I am away from my usual computer, so I can't tell you how the manifest should look like. More of that later.
Usually I just `Export` the project from Eclipse either as Runnable JAR file or just a Jar file (depending the usage).
Did you solve the problem?

Comment: What IDE you are using?